# Python class iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I have a class of the node which contain his parent and want to create iterator on it. Here is my try:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._parent = parent

    def __iter__(self):
        self = self.parent

    def __next__(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self = self.parent
            return self
```

But when I try to loop over the instance, it's never stops and returns the same value, what I did wrong?

Comment: There's nothing in the class to iterate over. What data type is `self.parent`?

Comment: You iterate over a *collection* of `Node` objects, not a `Node` itself.

Comment: Why is your `Node` class *an iterator*, you probably want to defined a `NodeIterator` class, and make `Node` and *iterable*, although, normally, `Node` objects themselves wouldn't be iterable, but some container class, like `NodeList` or whatever, *would* be iterable.

Comment: Also, your `__iter__` method returns `None`, when it should return `self` since you are implementing an *iterator*, although, you shouldn't be doing that to begin with. You should be implementing an *iterable*, where `__iter__` returns an iterator. Note, `self = self.parent` doesn't *have an affect on anything*, it simply reassigns the `self` local variable, and then the funciton returns `None`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're trying to keep track of the current node in the iterator by assigning to `self`, which is just a local variable, so nothing is actually updated.

The correct way would be to extract an iterator class and keep track of the current node there:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent

    def __iter__(self):
        return NodeIterator(self)


class NodeIterator:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.next_node = node

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.next_node is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            current_node = self.next_node
            self.next_node = self.next_node.parent
            return current_node
```

This can be used like so:

```
root = Node()

inner_1 = Node(root)
leaf_1 = Node(inner_1)

inner_2 = Node(root)
inner_2_1 = Node(inner_2)
leaf_2 = Node(inner_2_1)

for node in leaf_2:
    # will loop through:
    # leaf_2,
    # inner_2_1;
    # inner_2,
    # root
```